# Injecting IHttpContextAcessor into a Binding Model inside an Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a controller action method:

```
public void Register([FromBody]RegisterTenantCommand message)
{
    ...
}
```

And I have class **RegisterTenantCommand** with *constructor*:

```
public class RegisterTenantCommand
{
    public RegisterTenantCommand(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(httpContextAccessor) { }
}
```

But when I launch my app and execute this action, I have **httpContextAccessor = null**.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why do you even need dependencies on commands? If you want to use Command/Handler pattern, then command is a pure message, no dependencies and you resolve the command handler for it which process the message

Comment: I use CQRS pattern and I want to get db name from url in my multi-tenancy app.

Comment: Yes, but in CQRS commands are mere messages, they have no logic in them

Comment: Why? In my implementation I add _Execute_ method, that operates with entities from db context.

Comment: For the reason you have it now. Injecting dependencies into model classes is always difficult and you tightly couple messages to other stuff. In your case you couple it to the infrastructure (`IHttpContextAccessor` is very ASP.NET Core specific and with your implementation it leaks into your domain/business logic)

Comment: I had this problem and solved it by injection, frothemore I strongly agree with @Tseng

Comment: @Soren: Not sure its the same issue, as he should got exception that `IHttpContextAccessor` can't be resolved and I don't think the model binder invokes any but parameterless constructor. By default the controller action parameters aren't resolved via DI at all, unless one uses the `[FromService]` attribute in front of the action parameter to resolve it. I just dunno if its possible to combine `[FromBody][FromService]` on the same parameter. But even then it *feels wrong*.

Comment: @Tseng good point, let's see what happens next

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are confusing commands with commands from UI frameworks (like WPF+MVVM implementation of `ICommand` interface).

The current implementation also kind of violates the SRP principle, where a class should only be responsible for one thing. You're basically handing input (binding it to the user values) and executing it as well as handling the execution logic in it.

Commands in Command/Handler or CQRS pattern are mere messages, they only contain data (which may or may not be serialized and sent via message bus to be processed by other background processes).

```
// ICommand is a marker interface, not to be confused with ICommand from WPF
public class RegisterTenantCommand : ICommand
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The command handler is consists if an marker interface and an implementation of it (1:1 relation, exactly 1 handler for 1 command).

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Handle(T command);
}

public class RegisterTenantCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<RegisterTenantCommand>
{
    private readonly IHttpContext context;

    // You should really abstract this into a service/facade which hides
    // away the dependency on HttpContext
    public RegisterTenantCommandHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.context = contextAccesspor.HttpContext;
    }

    public void Handle(RegisterTenantCommand command)
    {
        // Handle your command here
    }
}
```

Once registered either automatically when using 3rd party IoC like Autofac or manually with built-in IoC (here I'll use built-in):

```
services.AddTransient<ICommandHandler<RegisterTenantCommand>, RegisterTenantCommandHandler>();
```

You can inject it, either in action or controller or any other service:

```
public class TenantController 
{
    public TenantController(ICommandHandler<RegisterTenantCommand> registerTenantHandler)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or action

```
public Task<IActionResult> RegisterTenant(
    [FromBody]RegisterTenantCommand command,
    [FromService]ICommandHandler<RegisterTenantCommand> registerTenantHandler
)
{
    registerTenantHandler.Handle(command);
}
```

Of course you can abstract this further to only inject one single interface class which will resolve and handle all commands, then call it `generalCommandHandler.Handle(command)` and its implementation would resolve and handle it.

Comment: What do you mean by this? "// You should really abstract this into a service/facade which hides away the dependency on HttpContext". What service?

Comment: HttpContext is something that is very tightly coupled to ASP.NET Core framework. Let's assume the registration and creating of database is a very time consuming operation, then you may not want to run that inside of ASP.NET Core especially not during the request. Instead you'd want to have a background task (i.e. Azure Web Job) do it. In an Azure Web Job there is no HttpContext, so you would have to create your  handler from scratch and duplicate logic. Depending on what you do on the context, unit testing may be very hard with it (many dependencies to mock for example)

Comment: If the parameter is essential to the execution of the command, yes. Or if its available only during the request and can't be queried afterwards. If it's something you can query afterwards (i.e. customer email stored in a database) and can be queried with the data provided in the command, then just inject your service or DbContext get the data in the handler.

Comment: I need to create a DataContext based on information from my request. So I inject HttpContext into CommandHandler and here create DatabaseContext based on request information came from the client. Is it the best way?

Comment: What kind of data/parameter is it? database/table name? some headers? json payload/model? a security token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127053/discussion-between-a-gladkiy-and-tseng).

Answer (score 0):

**The IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default (anymore)**

> IHttpContextAccessor can be used to access the HttpContext for the
>   current thread. However, maintaining this state has non-trivial
>   performance costs so it has been removed from the default set of
>   services.
>
> Developers that depend on it can add it back as needed:
>   `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`
>
> See [aspnet/Hosting#793](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793) for discussion.